# Running multiple websites - docker compose

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a docker-compose.yml file that looks something like this

```
version: "3.0"

volumes: 
  dbdata:
  .:

services:
  api:
    build:
      context: ./api
      args:
        - APP_NAME=${APP_NAME}
      dockerfile: dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - database
      - webserver
    volumes: 
      - ./api:/usr/local/share/${APP_NAME}

  database:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - ./dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    ports:
      - ${COMPOSE_DB_PORT}:3306

  webserver:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: webserver.dockerfile
    working_dir: "/usr/local/share/${APP_NAME}"
    volumes: 
      - ./api:/usr/local/share/${APP_NAME}
    restart: always
    ports:
      - ${COMPOSE_APP_PORT}:80
```

It has 3 services. a website, a database and a web server which works as expected.

Now I have another separate web project which is a CMS that uses the same database as the API project and I want to add it to this docker compose file but I can't figure out how to configure the web server service to handle requests from said 2 web sites. Should I add another web server for the cms?

I searched on google but I couldn't find something clear and most results were using old docker-compose version which I'm not familiar with.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Normally, you would have a separate web server, which exposes and publishes its own port (not on 80).

And you would have a dedicated listener (typically an NGiNX) to ensure a reverse proxy, in order to redirect the query to the right webserver, depending on its path or on the port.

[image: http://www.bogotobogo.com/DevOps/Docker/images/Docker-compose-reverse-proxy-nginx/nginx-reverse-proxy-pic.png] by [K Hong](https://plus.google.com/+KHongSanFrancisco).

See for instance "[Docker compose : NGINX reverse proxy with multiple containers](http://www.bogotobogo.com/DevOps/Docker/Docker-Compose-Nginx-Reverse-Proxy-Multiple-Containers.php) "